Order of exercise in full body workout routine
I do full body workouts from home on alternate days, and I was wondering if there is a particular order to target specific muscle groups of the body.
I usually go from bottom to top as in, legs first, then abs, chest and shoulders, and biceps. I haven't done much research on this particularly, but lately I've been thinking if this has the possibility of affecting my workouts in a negative way.
For context, I'm not looking to bulk up, my main focus is basically maintaining my health. My workouts usually last for about an hour and fifteen minutes and I am disciplined in maintaining my routine and diet. I do calisthenics and I also use dumb bells.

A better approach may be to prioritize the muscle group that needs the most improvement first so that you have optimal energy to attack that group.

Should I do a warm up first, or go straight onto the most difficult ones ?

Warm up in a dynamic (moving) fashion. Jump ropes, active calisthenics, dynamic stretches (Not static).

You should never attempt a difficult lift or exercise without properly "warming" up the appropriate muscle(s).
